# spring boot application properties for logging

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2, application.properties

I've seen many examples of configuring logging in Spring Boot, but what I look for is the simplest way to get the job done modifying this pattern in my application.properties:

```
logging.pattern.file= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
logging.file=/Users/alessandroargentieri/Desktop/try/application.log
```

This works pretty fine but what I would like to get is **set a MB limit** for the single file and set that every day I want to have a different log file (with the **date in the filename**).

Is possible to get this adding some lines in the application.properties without using XML or JSON files?

Comment: NO, you need to use logback xml for that

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override the default logging config with your own custom configuration. Spring boot provide logging support with minimum configuration and it's limited. It uses internally base.xml file which includes the below file-appender.xml:

```
<appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>
```

As you can see only few properties can be injected.

You can go through the below link to setup your custom configuration:

> https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-logback-with-spring-boot
>   https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but even adding this file, no output file is written in my external directory. I've also tried to substitute the ${...} values with: ${FILE_LOG_PATTERN} = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n and ${LOG_FILE}.%i = /Users/alessandroargentieri/Desktop/try/application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.xyz.log but no file is saved

Answer (score 0):

No. The easiest way to do that is with an extra xml file.

I'm using logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="c:/logs" />

<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>
            ${DEV_HOME}/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<logger name="ar.com" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</logger>

<root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</root>
```

Comment: thanks, but what's the single root element of the xml file?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand the question. The root tag is de default level for all the logs.